# java swing setlocation doesn't work for second time

Tags: java, swing, layout

Frame has `mainContentPane` with `layout manager = null
mainContentPane gamePanel`, which holds `jLabel Background at z-order 1` and a bunch of backgammon stones at `z- order 0,` if i set their positions before adding them to game panel, they end up in places i need them to be, but if im trying to set their places in game they all end ap at point 0,0 and calling get location says that its at a different location. Plese help me out on what im doing wrong with swing layout etc. setStones is the void that suppose to do it and getLocation after it ran gives locations I need, but everything is still at `0,0` on the screen

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener,
        MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int NUMBER_OF_STONES = 30;
    private JPanel mainContentPane;
    private JLayeredPane gamePanel;
    private JLabel background;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu menuGameTitle, aboutGameTitle;
    private JMenuItem newGame, exit, help;
    private JLabel[] stones;
    private Dimension preferredSize;
    private int stoneDragged = NUMBER_OF_STONES;
    private int clickX = 0;
    private int clickY = 0;
    private HashMap<game.Color, String> stoneImage;
    private HashMap<Integer, int[]> locations;

private int currStone;

public MainWindow() {
    createGUI();
    stoneImage = new HashMap<game.Color, String>();
    stoneImage.put(game.Color.BLACK, "SilverNSH.jpg");
    stoneImage.put(game.Color.WHITE, "GoldNSH.jpg");
    locations = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>();
    locations.put(0, new int[] {355,509});
    locations.put(1, new int[] {655, 509});
    .....
    currStone = 0;
    play();
}

private void createGUI() {
    preferredSize = new Dimension(800, 600);
    mainContentPane = new JPanel();

    mainContentPane.setLayout(null);

    mainContentPane.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
    gamePanel = new JLayeredPane();

    gamePanel.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);

    setSize(preferredSize);


    background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("BackGammon.jpg"));



    // adding stones;
    initStones();
    for (int i = 0; i < stones.length; i++) {
        gamePanel.add(stones[i], 0);
    }
    // setting background to 1 Z order
    gamePanel.add(background, 1);
    // set Z level to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < stones.length; i++) {
        gamePanel.setComponentZOrder(stones[i], 0);
    }
    mainContentPane.add(gamePanel);
    setContentPane(mainContentPane);
    pack();

}

private void initStones() {
    stones = new JLabel[NUMBER_OF_STONES];
    for (int i = 0; i < stones.length; i++) {
        if (i < NUMBER_OF_STONES / 2) {
            stones[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("SilverNSH.gif"));
        } else {
            stones[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("GoldNSH.gif"));
        }
        stones[i].setName(i + "");
        stones[i].setSize(40,40);
        stones[i].addMouseListener(this);
        stones[i].addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    stoneDragged = Integer.parseInt(e.getComponent().getName());
    clickX = e.getX();
    clickY = e.getY();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // no stone is dragged
    stoneDragged = NUMBER_OF_STONES;
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    // off screen check
    int yLoc;
    int xLoc;

    if (stoneDragged >= 0 && stoneDragged < NUMBER_OF_STONES) {
        xLoc = e.getComponent().getX() + e.getX() - clickX;
        yLoc = e.getComponent().getY() + e.getY() - clickY;
        stones[stoneDragged].setLocation(xLoc, yLoc);

        if (stones[stoneDragged].getX() <= 50)
            stones[stoneDragged].setLocation(51, 51);
        if (stones[stoneDragged].getY() <= 50)
            stones[stoneDragged].setLocation(51, 51);
        if (stones[stoneDragged].getX() >= 660)
            stones[stoneDragged].setLocation(659, 509);
        if (stones[stoneDragged].getY() >= 510)
            stones[stoneDragged].setLocation(659, 509);

    }

}



private void play() {

    setStones(board.getAmountArray(), board.getColorArray());



}

private void setStones(int[] amountArray, game.Color[] colorArray) {
    currStone = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Board.NO_OF_PLAYABLE_FIELDS;i++){
        if (amountArray[i] != 0) {
            placeStones(i, amountArray[i], stoneImage.get(colorArray[i]));
        }
    }
}

private void placeStones(int startPos, int amount, String picture) {
    for (int i = 0; i < amount;i++){
        stones[currStone].setIcon(new ImageIcon(picture));;
        if (startPos < 13) {
            stones[currStone].setLocation(locations.get(startPos)[0], locations.get(startPos)[1] - i*40);
        } else {
            stones[currStone].setLocation(locations.get(startPos)[0], locations.get(startPos)[1] + i*40);
        }
        stones[currStone].setSize(40, 40);
        currStone++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The best way would be to define proper LayoutManager

Comment: Error in code, found it. Pictures are not jpeg, they are gif, Sorry for this. everything works.

Comment: @StanislavL impossible to add layout manager to what i need, by impossible means very complicated

Comment: What's so complicated? It's just a grid in fact with some gaps